# Mouse wheel scroll in Polymer core-scroll-header-panel not working, when mouse is over core-toolbar

Tags: polymer

This is the demo from polymer-project.org for core-scroll-header-panel:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html

**What's wrong:**

put mouse over some list item and scroll mouse wheel down
=> you will see that all the content (list) is scrolled and core-toolbar changes its height to some minimal height and then scrolled up over the screen.
*Everything is OK.*

Now put mouse somewhere on the core-toolbar and scroll mouse wheel down.
=> nothing will happen

**The question is:**

what should I do to have the same scroll for mouse pointing over content and for core-toolbar both.

For example, page from documentation has no such problems (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scroll-header-panel). Seems like it uses other polymer components (or maybe not the polymer, I don't know).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `core-scroll-header-panel`'s `headerContainer` (inside its Shadow DOM) is blocking the scrolling.

One possible solution is to disable it from receiving touch or mouse events by setting the `pointer-events` to `none`.

```
core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #headerContainer {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: One addition: to work, your <style> tag must have 'shim-shadowdom' property. So, this should look like: <style shim-shadowdom> ...solution is here... </style>. Demo page has this property, but when I started from scratch I stuck. So, maybe this notice can be useful